# rotate gravity vector for realistic object move

Tags: math, box2d, physics

i have a gravity vector (0, -9.8) for a world and an object. this object is attached to the world. How can i calculate the gravity if i modify the rotation of the world?

i.e. if i rotate the world 10 degrees to the left, the object should start to move to the left.

The friction si 0 so we have an ideal case. I need a real solution to make the world behave as in real life.

Thanks!

Comment: Just rotate the gravity vector by the same amount?

Comment: Are you asking how to rotate a 2D vector? Or how to handle an object on an inclined plane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what rotation matrices are for: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix